# Query turned into a CPU gobbling monster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, performance, query-performance

I have a SP who's execution time went from 5 minutes > 20 minutes > 30 minutes > 53 minutes over four days

Waits were showing increasing CPU and suspended status

I isolated a single query that pegs the CPU

```
UPDATE thing.table
SET YYYYMM = 
CASE 
  WHEN 
    DAY(SnapshotDate) = 1
    OR 
  SnapshotDate = (SELECT MAX(SnapshotDate) FROM thing.table) 
  THEN CAST(FORMAT(DATEADD(day,-1,snapshotdate),'yyyyMM') AS INT)
  ELSE NULL
END
```

I ran it again, adding `WITH (RECOMPILE)` at the end - no difference

I ran `UPDATE STATISTICS thing.table` - no difference

It would be interesting to run it and get the actual plan but I don't want to peg the CPU for an hour. I checked `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` but it appears to only have the estimated plan not the actual plan

I rewrote using `CONVERT` instead of `FORMAT` (because I am suspicious of new things) - no difference

So I rewrote like this and took execution back down to a few seconds:

```
BEGIN TRAN;

UPDATE thing.table
SET YYYYMM = NULL;

UPDATE thing.table
SET YYYYMM = CAST(FORMAT(DATEADD(day,-1,snapshotdate),'yyyyMM') AS INT)
WHERE 
(
DAY(SnapshotDate) = 1 
OR
SnapshotDate = (SELECT MAX(SnapshotDate) FROM thing.table) 
);

COMMIT TRAN;
```

The table has about 150,000 records in it. It's quite possible that it recently had a lot more records dumped in it, skewing statistics, but why would `WITH(RECOMPILE)` and `UPDATE STATISTICS` not fix that?. It takes a daily snapshot and possibly the number of records increased due to end of month.

So the questions are:

1. Is *actual* query plan stored anywhere?, to save me running it interactively?
2. Normally when a query suddenly takes forever it stale statistics but that doesn't seem to be the case here

This is my version of SQL Server

> > Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64)   Apr 20 2015 17:29:27   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Here are the slow and fast query plans. No suprise they are different because they are doing different things:

Slow Plan:

[image: Slow Query Plan]

Fast Plan:

[image: Fast Query Plan]

I notice slowpoke uses an loop join and fasty uses a hash match.

I notice the small leg of the loop join has filter

`[Expr1006]=DB.thing.table.[SnapshotDate]`. Maybe that wasn't so small anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first query is so slow because it will do a full table scan on `thing.table` for every row in that table for which `DAY(SnapshotDate) <> 1`. So if you have 100k rows in the table in the worst case you'll do 100k scans which means reading through 10 billion rows. If the table is small enough it'll stay in memory so your parallel query will appear to burn through CPU.

You can tell by looking at the query plan carefully. The scan is on the inner side of a nested loop join. If that's not your cup of tea you can try [live query statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/live-query-statistics) to see the query as it executes. That way you can get some of the information from the actual plan without needing the query to finish. There's no way to save off old actual plans without setting up extended events.

The second query is faster because the query optimizer is freer to rearrange the elements of the query due to the lack of the `CASE` expression. Instead of calculating the subquery for `MAX(SnapshotDate)` once per row the calculation is done once per query.

You'll definitely want to fix this query in some way or the execution time will continue to grow quadratically with the number of rows in the table. One workaround would be to add an index to the `SnapshotDate` column. The subquery will still execute once for each row but getting the maximum value will be a very cheap operation. A better way is to save off the value of the subquery to a local variable and to use that in your `UPDATE` query. Unless you have to worry about concurrency that shouldn't be an issue.

You can also stick to the fix that you found if you want. One suggestion that can help in some cases (depending on the table structure) would be to add a where clause to your first `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE thing.table
SET YYYYMM = NULL
WHERE YYYYMM IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for that fantastic explanation. I was kind of suspicious of that `MAX(SnapshotDate)`. It's a batch process and it won't change per process. So I loaded that into a variable and referred to the variable and it _also_ fixed the issue. So the 'threshold' that was hit here to cause the query to run so slow was purely rowcount, nothing to do with statistics. Thanks so much for your answer, that's exactly what I was after, and I learnt something new about writing queries that the optimiser can juggle more effectively

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to break the query as follows:

```
--select MAX(SnapshotDate) only once
DECLARE @MAX_SnapshotDate datetime  --use the appropriate data type
SELECT @MAX_SnapshotDate=MAX(SnapshotDate) FROM thing.table

--Create computed column
ALTER TABLE thing.table
ADD DAY_SnapshotDate as (DAY(SnapshotDate)) PERSISTED

UPDATE thing.table
SET YYYYMM = NULL;

UPDATE thing.table
SET YYYYMM = CAST(FORMAT(DATEADD(day,-1,snapshotdate),'yyyyMM') AS INT)
WHERE 
SnapshotDate = @MAX_SnapshotDate

UPDATE thing.table
SET YYYYMM = CAST(FORMAT(DATEADD(day,-1,snapshotdate),'yyyyMM') AS INT)
WHERE 
DAY_SnapshotDate = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. It turns out just loading the SnapshotDate into a variable did the trick.